# Mustache: How to downcase first letter

Tags: java, mustache, swagger-codegen

I'm using a mustache template in order to generate some code using Java.

I'd like to downcase the first letter of a field.

Is there some way to get it?

I need to transform it directly. I'm generating C# code.

**EDIT**

I'm using [Swagger Codegen tool](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) in order to be able to generate a client according to a API Specification.

This tool is using mustache templates for generating an output. So, there's a template for each language you need. See [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/resources/csharp), in order to watch the mustache templates that Swagger Codegen provides.

I'm modifying these in order to customize the C# code I want to reach.

```
{{#apiInfo}}
{{#apis}}
    this.{{classname}} = new {{apiPackage}}.{{classname}}(this.Configuration);
{{/apis}}
{{/apiInfo}}
```

It has to generate something like:

```
this.UserAPI = new Api.UserAPI(this.Configuration);
```

I'd like to get:

```
this.userAPI = new Api.UserAPI(this.Configuration);
```

Comment: It's definitely not the same.

Comment: The answer would be quite the same, mustache doesn't give you the opportunity to update the value. So you will need to update it in Java (in this case)

Comment: More information is required, as well as code. You are using Java/C#/mustache? What? Do you mean Javascript rather than Java? Please give evidence of your javascript object literal, your view and any backend code you find appropriate.

Comment: I've detailed a bit more my needs. I hope I've explained so well.

Comment: This is not explained well. Provide full but succinct code to accompany your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the question is specific to swagger codegen tool they have lambda functions for mustache.

```
{{#lambda.camelcase_param}}{{name}}{{/lambda.camelcase_param}}
```

Try:

```
this.{{#lambda.camelcase_param}}{{classname}}{{/lambda.camelcase_param}} = new {{apiPackage}}.{{classname}}(this.Configuration);
```

Look for examples in template:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/resources/csharp/modelGeneric.mustache

Comment: More documentation on https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/templating.md#mustache-lambdas

Comment: @atrujillofalcon thats perfect! Exactly what I needed!